# I cant verify my contract. It is very basic code

Tags: remix, bsc, verify, binance-smart-chain

I cant verify my contract. It is very basic code. I cant understand why.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBEUl.jpg

Comment: I cant verify my contract. It is very basic code. I cant understand why. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrQM3.jpg

Comment: Please send the code you are using, there is a high probability that the code does not match

Comment: https://justpaste.it/c1w04

Comment: Without data.push() in constructor . It is works. Why?

Comment: The code is simple and does not import anything, it should not be a problem, check that your code does not have any problems in terms of syntax, pay attention to these points. Compiler version, optimization They must be entered correctly in ether scan. Have you followed these tips?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand, You must put the arguments of the constructor in this site and enter the encoded data in the etherscan of the constructor section. https://abi.hashex.org/

Comment: Or in the Auto Pars section, you can get the correct output just by inserting the ABI

Comment: my constructor takes no arguments.

Comment: Use auto pars section and try with your abi

Answer (score 1):

copy both "what we are looking for" and "what we got" bytecode to a text editor and see where they differ. If "what we are looking for" bytecode has an extra set of bytes at the very end, it's probably encoded constructor parameters that are missing. You can copy that portion and enter it on the inout screen. If there is a big chunk in the middle - it might be a library that should be linked. If differences are in multiple places - it may be compiler version or optimizer parameters that didn't match. In any case, comparing these two bytecodes usually can give a good clue to what is lacking.